tkinter create a widget if not exist and update if exist by click on a item in listbox
i have a have listbox that is bind to itemlistcallback function. i want to create label by clicking on a item in listbox for first time and update it if it was clicked more than once. the result is no matter on what item i click on, only the last label change.
its a receipt system for a restaurant that is going to increase quantity of item by clicking on them.
def itemlistcallback(event):
       selection = event.widget.curselection()
       if selection:
           global rowcount
           global itemqty
           global itemid
           global itemcount
           print(rowcount)
           rowcount +=1
           index = selection[0]
           data = event.widget.get(index)
           orderitemslist.insert(0,data)

           if data[0] not in itemset:
              itemid = "itemnamelbl"+str(data[0])
              itemcount = "itemcount"+str(data[0])
              itemid = Label(orderitemframe, text= data[1], font= ('Helvetica 12 bold'))
              itemcount = Label(orderitemframe, text=itemqty, font= ('Helvetica 12 bold'))
              itemid.grid(row=rowcount, column=1, padx = 0, pady = 0,sticky='n')
              itemcount.grid(row=rowcount, column=0, padx = 0, pady = 0,sticky='n')
              itemset.append(data[0])

           else:         
              itemqtyy = itemcount.cget("text")
              itemcount.config(text = itemqtyy+1)
           

       else:
          pass
   itemslist.bind("<<ListboxSelect>>", itemlistcallback)

i'd tried winfo_exists() to check if a widget exist or not, after getting no result, i make a list of what ids added to create a widget.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

what im asking is how to create a widget(label) by clicking on a item in a listbox for the first time, and update same widget if i click on the same item in listbox. the problem is its only update the last widget that is created.

no, the problem was i didnt know how to refer to widget by its name, i did it using nametowidget. thanks alot.
